# yyyy-mm-dd to mon dd yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and I need to convert this date value `2018-02-23`
to something like this `Feb 23 2018`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server 2012+ has a `FORMAT()` function which could help you to format the date

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'MMM dd yyyy')
```

You could also use conversion function `convert()`

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), getdate(), 100)
```

Comment: I'd recommend `CONVERT` over `FORMAT`. The latter is much slower (about 3-4 times in my experience) compared to the former.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘MON DD, YYYY’)         — JAN 03, 2012
```

See the link below.

https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/